# Searching and displaying array/arrays for specific array baed on the user's input

Tags: c++, arrays, function, object, display

I have been trying to search the array for a specific car (array) based on the choice between: Make, Model, Year or number of Cylinders and display the items retrieved by the search on the screen from here.
My data in the text file presented here was passed already into arrays and printed as:

```
Volkswagen
Jetta
2016
4

Jeep
Wrangler
2008
6

Toyota
Corolla
1999
4

Chevy
Malibu
2018
6

Chevy
Malibu
2014
6

BMW
320i
2014
6

Jeep 
GrandCharokeeLaredo
2006
6

Ford
Fusion
2012
4

Chevy
Equinox
2015
4

Volkswagen
Jetta
1998
4
```

My problem is that I do not know how to transfer from a user input (ex: "Volkswagen") from a menu and display the arrays with that characteristic.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

class Cars
{
private:
    // Private variables of cars
    string make;
    string model;
    int year;
    int cylinders;
public:

    // Function within the objects
    void setMake(string m) { make = m; }
    string getMake() { return make; }

    void setModel(string mo) { model = mo; }
    string getModel() { return model; }

    void setYear(int y) { year = y; }
    int getYear() { return year; }

    void setcylinders(int c) { cylinders = c; }
    int getCylinders() { return cylinders; }


};

int main()
{
    //Opening the file
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("cars.txt");

    // Variables for car characteristics
    string make;
    string model;
    int year;
    int cylinders;

    string inMa;
    string inMo;
    int inYe;
    int inCy;

    // Object array
    Cars car[10];

    cout << " Display of available automobiles: " << endl;
    cout << endl;


    // Reading from file and passing into array
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        if (inputFile >> make >> model >> year >> cylinders)
        {

            car[x].setMake(make);
            car[x].setModel(model);
            car[x].setYear(year);
            car[x].setcylinders(cylinders);


            cout << right << setw(7) << " Car #" << x << " " << endl;
            cout << "Maker: " << make << endl;
            cout << "Model: " << model << endl;
            cout << "Year made: " << year << endl;
            cout << "Number of cylinders: " << cylinders << endl;
            cout << endl;

        }
    inputFile.close();

    int selection;
    cout << " Selection of automobiles:" << endl;
    cout << " Select an option to describe your car/cars. " << endl;
    cout << " ----------------------------" << endl;
    cout << " 1. Maker of Car: " << endl;
    cout << " 2. Model of Car: " << endl;
    cout << " 3. Year of the Car made: " << endl;
    cout << " 4. Number of cylinders: " << endl;
    cin >> selection;
    if (selection == 1)
    {
        cout << " Who is the maker of the car? " << endl;
        // Need help displaying array that contain a specific variable 
        // Ex: All arrays that contain "Jeep"
    }
    else if (selection ==2)
    {
       cout << " What is the model of the car? " << endl;
       // Need help displaying array that contain a specific variable
    }
    else if (selection ==3)
    {
       cout << " What was the year the car was made? " << endl;
       // Need help displaying array that contain a specific variable
    }
    else if (selection ==4)
    {
       cout << " How many cylinders does the car have?" << endl;
       // Need help displaying array that contain a specific variable
    }
    else
    {
       cout << "Enter a valid response" << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

How can I match arrays with the user input and output it the user based on the object arrays? I am not worried if the user misinputs the variable during "cin".

Comment: How about reading the search text/value from input and then comparing all array entries (the resp. member) with that search text/value in a loop? It would look similar to the loop for your file reading.

Comment: Hint: You haven't done anything with the getters yet.